# ImageLightBox arrow not working with images of same link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have installed ImageLightBox on my blogger but the arrow is not working properly eg: If i have five images out of which 2nd and 4th are same images with same link. When i click on image link ImageLightBox starts. Clicking on arrow shows next image but after reaching 3rd image it comes back to 2nd image and then 3rd and again 2nd and repeated ..

here is the fiddle : jsfiddle.net/Bloggerz/a9yary1x/4/

Comment: Anyone please answer

Comment: This is because of this code in your js `$target = $(selector + '[href="' + $('#imagelightbox').attr('src') + '"]'),` it always selects the first element in the dom; As when you reach to 4th element you actually seeing 2nd not 4th to prevent this strange behavior change the selector to something else or make urls different;

Comment: Any Suggestion for edits in code instead of changing url